# Synology Cloud Station Server notifications

Tags: backup, synology

I have multiple clients backing up to a Synology NAS using Cloud Station Server. I purchased this setup to replace my previous solution of running a local Crashplan server. One feature that I miss of Crashplan is email updates when a device isn't backing up or an email showing the weekly status of all clients / latest backup date. Is this possible with Synology Cloud Station Server?

Answer (score 1):

I am just getting acquainted with this back-up structure having to move on from using code42. Certainly I get regular messages (almost too many) about existing processes - check this link out which includes any process running on the NAS you ask for. 
https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_notification_filter
Cheers
Rick

Comment: Thank you - coincidently I am moving from Crashplan/Code42 also to Synology. I receive some notification (app updates, when a user logs in, incorrect password attempt, etc) but nothing related to the status of a Cloud Station backup...